# Encoding and decoding with Microsoft SQL Server using Postman

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion, postman, varbinary

I wrote the following script to be used through Web API:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[LWP_WEB_ENCODE]
    @order_no int, 
    @dept varchar(2)
    
    DECLARE @customer_no int 
    SET @customer_no = (SELECT customer_no FROM table_order 
                        WHERE order_no = @order_no)
        
    DECLARE @string varchar (4000), @encoded VARBINARY(max)

    SELECT @string = CAST(@order_no AS varchar) + '-' + 
                     CAST(@customer_no AS varchar) + '-' + @dept_abbreviation
            
    SELECT @encoded = CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), @string)
    SELECT @encoded AS 'encoded'
```

When I execute the query with the following paramters:

```
exec [LWP_WEB_LWP_WEB_ENCODE] @order_no = 7267587, @dept_abbreviation = 'S'
```

I get the following string back

[image]

I then do the same thing through postman in an effort to simulate the web calls and get something completely different

[image]

I'm not sure why its behaving like this - but also I have a script that decodes the string in the opposite direction and this particular value doesn't work

The decoded procedure basically just runs this

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), @encoded) AS 'decoded'
```

When I run my script

```
exec [LWP_WEB_DECODE] @encoded = 0x373236373538372D38373132323938372D53
```

I get this in SQL

[image]

However then I try to run the value returned in postman it hates it
For some reason its not encoding it as I do in SQL and its returning a string and not a hex value

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stored procedure returns binary data.  SSMS displays binary data by encoding it in a hex string.  JSON and XML can't directly contain binary data, but most often use [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) to encode it as a string rather than using a hex string.